# Star ratings not working

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, less

I built simple star ratings to display on the testimonial page on CodePen and it displayed the 5 stars OK, but they will not show up on the webpage. Outside of the "star-wrap" div is not hidden.

HTML

```
<div class="star-wrap">
    <span class="stars">
        <span style="width: 80%" />
     </span>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.star-wrap { width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; }
.stars {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 45px;
    position: relative;
    color: #476b8c;

    &:after {
        content: "☆☆☆☆☆";
    }

span {
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   overflow: hidden;

   &:after {
       content: "★★★★★";
    }
    }
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/magnix2k/esog7ueh/8/) - not working like on the webpage

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/magnix/pen/VXyZjd?q=rating%20stars&order=popularity&depth=everything&show_forks=false) - works OK

Comment: Your codepen works because you set it to use LESS but you didn't configure your fiddle to use SCSS. If you had, it'd [work](https://jsfiddle.net/juueateu/)

Comment: Thank you! I have never use LESS/SCSS before.

Comment: You haven't? Does that mean the "CSS" you have wasn't written by you? If so, shouldn't wherever you got it from have told you what preprocessor language was used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of codepen supports preprocessor code while JSFiddle doesn't support preprocessor same as a browser.

But you can use compiled CSS

```css
.star-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.stars {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 45px;
  position: relative;
  color: #476b8c;
}
.stars:after {
  content: "☆☆☆☆☆";
}
.stars span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.stars span:after {
  content: "★★★★★";
}
```

```html
<div class="star-wrap">
<span class="stars">
  <span style="width: 90%" />
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah! In fact I have never use LESS before. Thanks!